# Typescript, Type Object Is Not Generic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a type for an Object. But can't seem to get it right. This is what I have.

```
private test:Object<Test>;

this.test = {id : 'test'};

interface Test
{
   id : string;
}
```

This doesn't work. This gives me the following error:

> Type Object Is Not Generic

What is the right way (syntax) to create types for Objects like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define a class `Test`:

```
export class Test {
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
  /// ...
}
```

then

```
private test:Test;
```

**Update**: Sorry, didn't notice you have `Test` as `interface`. It's fine too.

So same usage, you don't need `Object<Test>`, just `Test`